# get element from function in Jquery Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a jquery function that needs to run a user function onclick of the element. The problem is that i need access to the element I am calling the function on. How would i go about accomplishing this. An example of the function is

```
                $("#domelement").yesNoDialog({
                 title:"Ineligible to Register",
                 message:"Stackoverflowtest",
                 yesFunction:function(){        
                     location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com"

                     //How do i grab an attribute from #domelement in here? ie $("domeElement").attr("stuff");

                 }
             });
```

The simplified version of the Jquery Method is as follows

```
(function($) {       
  $.fn.yesNoDialog = function(options) {     
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.yesNoDialog.defaultOptions, options);      
    this.each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(){
          options.yesFunction();
       });
    });     
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What's the problem? You're accessing `this` like you say you want. Are you getting errors?

Comment: Its just a function so yea you would be able to access the dom element you want there.

Comment: cant use this because $(this) is the actual function

Comment: use $.proxy() to set the context of 'this' in your yesFunction() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: Or implement it as a plugin, not a function.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in the element into the function and use it that way

```
                $("#domelement").yesNoDialog({
                 title:"Ineligible to Register",
                 message:"Stackoverflowtest",
                 yesFunction:function(element){     
                     location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com"

                     //How do i grab an attribute from #domelement in here? ie $("domeElement").attr("stuff");

                 }
             });
```

Pass the element into the function

```
(function($) {       
  $.fn.yesNoDialog = function(options) {     
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.yesNoDialog.defaultOptions, options);      
    this.each(function() {
      var that = this;
      $(this).click(function(){
          options.yesFunction(that); <--- Lets you use the element 
       });
    });     
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```